# Comparing Combinations of Regressors for Linear Regression Feature Selection

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models, feature-selection, misspecification

I'm trying to make a time series linear regression for forecasting purposes.  I have picked eight features that logically are tied to the independent variable (separate time series data sets).

I wrote some SAS code that loops through all of the combinations of the eight features creating a regression for each combination. I then order the data by R-Squared to decide the models' specification.

I've heard that this process can create in invalid model, but nobody that has said that has explained to me exactly why.  Can this create a mispecified model?  Are there other, better ways to create a valid model that maximizes explanatory power.

Comment: Are you measuring the R-squared using the training set?  Then certainly the model using all eight features will win.

Comment: @MatthewDrury yes, that is a good point.  I should've mentioned that I also consider adjusted R-Squared.  But I guess I should probably get the R-Squared from the test set.  That would be more meaningful.